Why won't my variable change value in my loop?
I'm in a beginner C++ class. I have to write a program that measures gravitational attraction between two spheres.
For some reason, when I run the code, my variable x (which is the distance between the two edges of the spheres) doesn't update throughout my loop, even though I have it set to do so, thus making none of the other variables change their value.
Is there any reason why this may be happening?
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

const double G = 6.67408e-11;

int main(){
    double m1 = 0.0;
    double m2 = 0.0;
    double r1 = 0.0;
    double r2 = 0.0;
    double x = 0.0;
    double d = 0.0;
    double initialX = x;
    double f = 0.0;
    
    cout << "Enter the Mass of the First Sphere in Kilograms: ";
    cin >> m1;
    if (m1 < 0){
        cout << "Error! Enter a Positive Number!" << endl;
        cout << "Enter the Mass of the First Sphere in Kilograms: ";
        cin >> m1;
    }
    cout << endl << "Enter the Radius of the First Sphere in Meters: ";
    cin >> r1;
    if (r1 < 0){
        cout << "Error! Enter a Positive Number!" << endl;
        cout << "Enter the Radius of the First Sphere in Kilograms: ";
        cin >> r1;
    }
    cout << endl << "Enter the Mass of the Second Sphere in Kilograms: ";
    cin >> m2;
    if (m2 < 0){
        cout << "Error! Enter a Positive Number!" << endl;
        cout << "Enter the Mass of the Second Sphere in Kilograms: ";
        cin >> m2;
    }
    cout << endl << "Enter the Radius of the Second Sphere in Kilograms: ";
    cin >> r2;
    if (r2 < 0){
        cout << "Error! Enter a Positive Number!" << endl;
        cout << "Enter the Radius of the Second Sphere in Kilograms: ";
        cin >> r2;
    }
    cout << endl <<"Enter the Distance Between the Edges of the Two Spheres in Meters: ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << endl;
    cout << setw(15) << "Distance" << setw(15) << "Force" << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------------" << endl;
    
    
    for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
        f = (G * m1 * m2) / sqrt(d);
        x = x - initialX / 100.0;
        d = x + r1 + r2;
        cout<< setw(15) << fixed << setprecision(2) << d << setw(15) << scientific << setprecision(5) << f << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

I've mostly just tried formatting my code differently, but to no avail. I'm really unsure why this isn't working.

The very first statement of the loop, f = (G * m1 * m2) / sqrt(d), divides by zero. d == 0.0 at that point.

x = x - initialX / 100.0; In your program, initialX is initialized to zero, and never changed afterwards. So this statement is a no-op, it doens't update the value of x. Nor is it updated anywhere else.

Taking a step back, you compute force f, but don't use it in any further computations. Shouldn't there be acceleration in there somewhere? That is, apart from programmatic mistakes, the physics don't look right either.

Gravitation is an inverse-square law, but you are currently coding it as inverse square-root!

Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that std::endl does. Use '\n' to end a line unless you have a good reason not to.

You could remove 95% of that code and still show the problem. In particular, instead of prompting for user input, just assign initial values to the variables.

Do you know how to place breakpoints and step threw the running code? Learning that would make fixing this issue a lot easier.

Small problems are easier to solve than big ones. Always do your best to keep problems small. Write a few lines, test the program. Write a few more, test the program. If you have a problem with a line, break that line e down into steps and isolate the step that's not working. This is especially important with the math. If an equation doesn't work, break it down and isolate the step that's not working. Focus on the small problems and the big problems become small problems of why two tested and separately-working blocks don't work together they way they should.

The problem is that initialX is zero so x = x - initialX/100.0 does not change x. You seem to think that when you input a value to x here cin >> x; that initialX will change as well, but this is not true. If you want initialX to have the initial value of x you must do initialX = x; after cin >> x;.
